# Get absolute page position of text in OpenOffice Writer

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

I have an elaborately formatted table in OpenOffice Writer. Is there a way I can get the actual position or coordinates of any given cell, like where I click on the box and can see exactly how many inches the cursor is from the edge of the page?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to say is "How can I see how many inches from the margin are my table cells?"

In that case you can hover over the table with your mouse and watch the marks.

Comment: It just says "Adjust Table Row." I can manually calculate by adding my margin space to what I can eyeball on the ruler, but it's not a very precise method - and with font sizes as small as I'm using, being off by .1 inch (or .24 cm) is obvious.